# error LGHT0204 : ICE17: Bitmap: 'WixUI_Bmp_Dialog' for Control: 'Bitmap' of Dialog: 'WelcomeDlg' not found in Binary table

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7

When i am building my Wix project I am getting the below errors:

error LGHT0204 : ICE17: Bitmap: 'WixUI_Bmp_Dialog' for Control: 'Bitmap' of Dialog: 'WelcomeDlg' not found in Binary table

The code is

```
<Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="130" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />
```

and we are creating "Id" for "WelcomeDlgBitmap" in WixUI_en-us.wxl like as shown below:
WixUI_Bmp_Dialog

I am getting many errors similar to this like as shown below:

I fixed this with the below Visual studio settings -> Tool Settings and set "Suppress ICE Validation". Can i go ahead and do like this?

Answer (score 5):

Add the following directive to the file where the installer UI is defined:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
```